# Moving ASP.NET project from TFS to GITHUB. Opening project says it is bound to source control on tfs server:

Tags: visual-studio, git, tfs, github, visual-studio-2012

I moved my project from tfs to github using git-tfs and now when I open the project it gives a message stating it is under TFS Server Version Control.

The message Says

```
Team Foundation Server Version Control

The solution you are opening is bound to source control on the following Team 
Foundation Server: http://tfs:8080/tfs/defaultcollection.  
Would you like to contact this server to try to enable source control integration.
```

I would really like to remove this myself and anyone else who opens the project does not get this message.

The code in tfs and github are still the same if that makes it easier to just redo the extract -> push to github process.  Or even better are there a few files I can try modify or changes in the UI I can make?

I seen one recommendation to go to 
File -> Source Control -> Advanced -> Change Source Control
but everything is listed as not connected currently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hard and fast way to clean this up is to delete the TFS bindings in the solution file.

Open the solution file in a text editor (notepad, notepad++, or the like) and look for the GlobalSection entitiled `GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl)`.

Delete this entire section - i.e. everything from `GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl)` to the next first occurence of `EndGlobalSection` - and save the solution file.

Once that's been propagated through (i.e. committed to GitHub and everyone has pulled down the change) you and anyone else opening the solution should no longer see the TFS messages.

Comment: I see the section.  Will make this change when I get home and test it.  Once this works I will mark your answer as the solution.  Thanks.